# JQuery DataTable Export Excel cannot apply Built in style to empty cell

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I am trying to apply style to excel by using attr('s', '20') from the button extension from jquery datatable. https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5
Below code is how I apply style to the 3rd child of a row:

```
$('#DataTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: function (xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                $('row[r!=1]', sheet).each(function () {
                    $(this).children().eq(2).attr('s', '20');//apply style to 3rd child of the row.
                });
            }
        }]...............
```

The problem is : When the cell is empty, the style wont be applied.

When the 3rd cell is an empty string or null on the datatable, the style won't be apply on excel file. I debugged the code and find out  $(this).children().eq(2) does not exist when the cell is an empty string. If the 3rd cell has some text in it, the style will be applied.

Does anyone know how to work around this? Or is there a way to apply style to the entire row.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried directly styling the row like this: `$('row[r!=1]', sheet).attr( 's', '20' )`?

Comment: I just tried it. It didn't work. Based on datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5, the build in style only apply to cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "createEmptyCells" : true,

Example
        { extend: 'excelHtml5', 
                                                                text: 'Export to Excel', 
                                                                "createEmptyCells" : true,
                                                                exportOptions: 
                                                                    {   title:null,
                                                                        orthogonal: 'export'
                                                                     }
                                                                },

Comment: I have set ```createEmptyCells``` to true, but when trying to write a value to a cell right after the table in the exported excel file nothing happen. It appears that the cells immediately after the table are still null for some reason. Here is my code for trying to insert a test value: ```$('c[r=A50] t', sheet).text('TEST');```

Answer (score 0):

To style the **third cell for each row excluding the header**, you need this selector:

```
$('row[r!=1] c:nth-child(3)', sheet).attr('s', '20');
```

The styling will apply even the cell is empty. Check [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMReYp) I created.

Comment: The 3rd cell was never created because there is no text in it, so c:nth-child(3) will be null, and then the style wont apply.

Comment: @Candice you can apply the style in the entire row instead.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. The cell was never created so that style wont apply, Shibani's solution actually works.